# Close listener after idle time

Tags: node.js, express

I've a simple [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) server that is started automatically.

It uses [express](/questions/tagged/express) to host the endpoint, which is started with a simple `app.listen(port);` command.

Since I've an automatic startup, I'd like to shutdown the server after an idle period - say 3 mins.

I've coded it manually just using the function below, which is called on each `app.post`:

```
//Idle timer
var timer;
function resetIdleTimer() {

    if (timer != null) clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        logger.info('idle shutdown');
        process.exit();
    }, 3 * 60 * 1000);

}
```

This seems a little crude though, so I wondered if there is an neater way (some sort of timer within `express` maybe).

Looking in the express docs I didn't see an easy way to configure this.

Is there a neater way to have this idle shutdown implemented?

Comment: how did you include the `nodejs` and `express` tags inline in your question?

Comment: @plato Like so: `[tag:nodejs]` and `[tag:express]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.listen()` returns a wrapped HTTP server (as can be seen here [in the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L531-L534)), on which you can then the [`.close()` method](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback).

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(port);
setTimeout(function() {
  server.close();
}, 3 * 60 * 1000);
```

This will prevent the server from accepting new connection. When it has stopped serving existing connections, it will gracefully stop. This will then stop Nodejs entirely.

*Edit:* You might also find this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1366) relevant.

Comment: ok - that's nicer than just terminating the process at least.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) . You can require it as a module into your application and it provides you with some functions that can help you achieve what you are looking for (such as `forever.stop(index)` which terminates the node process running at that index. Before terminating the process, you could retrieve the list of processes and manipulate the strings in order to get the uptime. Then, I would monitor the time that passes between server calls. If there is a gap of  3 minutes between requests, I would call `forever.stop()` in order to terminate the process.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's "crude" to use your timer solution; I would take a slightly different tack:

```
app.timeOutDate = new Date().valueOf() + 1000*60*3; // 3 minutes from now, in ms

function quitIfTimedout(req, res, next){
  if(new Date().valueOf() > app.timeOutDate){
    logger.info('idle shutdown');
    process.exit();
  } else {
    app.timeOutDate = new Date().valueOf() + 1000*60*3; //reset
    next();
  }
};

app.all('*', quitIfTimedout);
```

however this wont actually quit after 3 minutes, it would instead quit on the next request after 3 minutes. so that might not solve your problem

Comment: eek. So it would be idle idefinitely, then kill itself off when it finally gets asked for work. You're right - not quite what I'm after!